# Kubuntu 20.04 keeps perform black screen with NVIDIA

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, sddm

I have been trying Ubuntu 20.04 for two weeks. It worked well with NVIDIA graphic card.

Then I tried to install Plasma Desktop. If I choose "gdm3" on installation, everything goes well. NVIDIA works. If I choose SDDM, black screen after reboot. Then I purge NVIDIA drivers, and it works well with Intel HD graphics.

This week I have installed Kubuntu 20.04 and I click driver installations also at the Kubuntu installation dialogue. So black screen on first boot. Then Ctrl+Alt+F2 and purge NVIDIA. Then it worked.

It gives black screen immediately after I try to use NVIDIA with Kubuntu. I know that this case has been problem for many users. But I didn't understand anything from any explainations.

Is (K)ubuntu installers own NVIDIA driver packages doesn't suit for SDDM? (Always it downloads Nvidia 340) Should I download and install manually? And what driver should I download?
I will put my neofetch result down.

Thank you in advance.

neofetch:
[image: neofetch]

Answer (score 1):

Give nvidia-460 a try. See if that works for you.

Also check that you have linux-headers packages installed. They don't install by default and nvidia drivers don't build without them. Yet they are not listed as a dependency.

Execute this command:
`sudo apt install linux-headers-5.8.0-50 linux-headers-5.8.0-50-generic`
Either it will say that it had nothing to do, or it will install these all-important but always missed packages.

Then try installing nvidia-460 driver by any convenient means.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Code didn't made any difference. I have installed nvidia 460. It didn't made black screen problem but now on Additional Drivers only active option is "Continue using a manually installed driver" (other two drivers are inactive and not choosable). I think I will continue with dual boot Ubuntu and Kubuntu.